# How to pass flask arguments to decorator on flask function

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, decorator

Actually i am trying to write a decorator for logging the userid which is being passed from frontend in json format.

So the requirement is to read the data passed in requests inside  the decorator. I am not understanding the flow of how to read the content passed inside decorator.

```
  def logger_testing(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def log_test(*args, **kwargs):
            print ("inside looger")
            # logger.info(log("data has been inserted for ",userid))
            print ("args",**kwargs)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            print ("outside")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return log_test

    @app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
    @logger_testing
    def hello():
        content = request.get_json()
        print ("content",content)
        print ("executed")
        return "hello"
```

Comment: You can use `request.get_json()` inside your decorator.

Comment: Thanks for answer it works.I know it is lame to ask, but can you please explain the concept behind this.

Comment: `request` is a special global object that can be accessed from anywhere while a request is being handled, not just directly inside the function decorated with app.route. The technical details are here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/reqcontext/